# How do I send articles viewed in my web browser to my Kindle from android

Tags: ebook-reader, amazon-kindle

In my desktop web browser I have the Amazon "Send to Kindle" add-in which produces a readable version of a web page and sends the article to my Kindle for reading later.

I use this primarily for newspaper articles to read them later on a larger more readable screen and I don't usually have an internet connection when reading articles on my Kindle.

**What I'm looking for is a product or solution which achieves the same on my Android device.**

What I've tried already:

- I can print web pages to PDF from my Android device and send these PDFs to my Kindle, this is not ideal as I just want the text content to read.
- The Instapaper Android app lets me send a *link* to an article to my Kindle, but it doesn't send the readable version of articles it has created. I can push articles to my Kindle from the Instapaper website, but then I might as well use the Send to Kindle add in.
- I tried to install the Readability Android app, but this refused to let me create a new account from the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something similar too - there doesn't seem to be an official Amazon option.

The closest thing I can find is 'Push to Kindle' by FiveFilters: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fivefilters.kindleit